# how to configure nginx for 2 different projects (2 different docker compose files)

Tags: docker, nginx, configuration, share

I have 2 projects:

1. `myapi` that serves all api calls
2. `django_web` that uses myapi.

If I place them on 2 different servers - they work great (as they are completely independent) however, I wish to have them both on the same server (name it: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) but I couldn't figure our how they can both share the same nginx. I'm using docker and it complains that 0.0.0.0:443 is already in use.

myapi nginx configuration:

```
upstream flask_server {    
   server flaskapp2:8000;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

 location / {
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
 
server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://flaskapp2:8000;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;       
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1; 
}

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

and for the django_web

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;        
}


server {
 client_max_body_size 20M;
 listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location /static/ {
      alias /www/static/;
    }

    location /websocket/ {
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   #proxy_pass http://$server_name:8080/websocket/my_random_number/;
   proxy_pass http://$server_name:8080;

 }



location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_pass http://$server_name:8080;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

}
}

docker settings for myapi:

```
  nginx:
image: "nginx:1.13.5"
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
volumes:
  - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./static:/static
  - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/ 
restart: always
networks:
  - my_network
depends_on: 
  - flaskapp2
container_name: hnginx
```

and for the django_web:

```
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: "nginx"
    container_name: hnginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./config/example:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static2:/static
      - ./media2:/media
      - .:/www
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/ 
      - ./config/html_pages:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - hnetwork
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want deal with a sharing port across the same host with containers, I'd suggest you to use a middleware service, called [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/).

Put your two services served by Nginx behind Traefik. Traefik will route your web requests incoming on 443 to the good service, following domain name or path prefix rules.

Here is a short docker-compose implementation suggestion:

```yaml
myapi:
  [Your configuration]
  expose:
    - 80
    - 443
  labels:
    - [Traefik configuration labels here]

django:
  [Your configuration]
  expose:
    - 80
    - 443
  labels:
    - [Traefik configuration labels here]

traefik:
  [Traefik configuration]
  ports:
     # single access point on 443 that route incoming request
     - 443:443
```

Comment: thank you. Is this (Traefik) is instead of nginx or in a dition to?

Comment: I use it on production environment in addition to my Nginxs services. From my Nginxs services, I expose 80 port, then I configure Traefik with Let's encrypt for HTTPs and you are ready to go !